# Change the voting buttons after you've submitted a vote

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm often using the Android app on a high latency connection, and there's often a delay of a few seconds between clicking on the vote button and it actually changing colour.

The problem is that I'm not sure if I clicked the button correctly (I might have missed), so I'm tempted to tap it again. Still nothing happens, so I'm panicked that I just cancelled the vote I just attempted, so I click again. Often I'll click a few more times, because I'm basically in voting limbo right now.

This makes voting quite stressful.

Perhaps the voting buttons could change to greyed/faded out, or some kind of waiting animation while the request is being handled?

Comment: Possible workaround: 1. Tap vote button. 2. Breathe in through your nose slowly until your lungs are full. 3. Hold breath for a count of three. 4. Exhale slowly through your mouth. 5. Smile! Your vote counted.

Comment: Does the app not instantly change the voting button? It's supposed to work like so: Tap up arrow. Up arrow becomes red reacting to touch. Let go. Up arrow stays red while all to server happens. If an error occurs, revert state change and show it, else keep it red.

Comment: @kasra That's not what I'm getting...

Comment: @fredley bah alright, I'll set up a high latency connection and see what's going on, thanks.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi so shouldn't this be marked as a bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard good point

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi thanks! By the way, don't you get inline retag option, as seen in [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5TE30.png)? It's 10K privilege, but I was sure diamond grants all privileges. Maybe we just found a bug in the diamonds!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I do, I just always forget to use it since it's hidden unless you mouse over it.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi oh... and I was looking forward to glorious bug report. Have a good day, and good luck hunting down the bug reported here. :)